# How to disable redux-toolkit's "non-serialiable value" warning for tests?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I'm passing/injecting React components with Redux, utilizing redux-toolkit. Since they're not serializable, I've successfully disabled the check with that configuration:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ...
  },
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    console.log('IN MIDDLEWARE'); // gets logged in tests, so jests gets to this point
    return getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false, // works in the app, but doesn't in tests - I still see the error log there
    });
  },
});
```

This works fine in the application, but for some reason doesn't not help to suppress the error `A non-serializable value was detected in an action` getting logged in jest tests. I don't understand why it's still there and cluttering my test logs.

Comment: Need to see the test code. Sounds like you've mocked some part of Redux which prevents this configuration from taking hold - but that is just a WAG. Are you using a custom render function for your tests? If so, is the store configuration there exactly the same as above?

Comment: @RandyCasburn OMG, you're right! The Redux store from above gets overriden by a custom rendering after its initialisation. What a stupid oversight on my side! Anyway, in case you write it an answer, I'll gladly accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using a custom render function for your tests. The store configuration there needs to be
exactly the same as above.